# 3 and 2 column full screen (width & height) layouts (CSS)

Tags: css, xhtml

I was wondering if there were any simple examples that did the following

```
    * A right and a left fixed column with a fluid center. 
      With full height and width and a header and footer.
    * A single left fixed column with a fluid content column 2. 
      With full height and width and a header and footer.
    * A single right fixed column with a fluid content column.
      With Full height and width and a header and footer.
```

I've tried some methods (such as the ones listed on listapart) but they seemed really complicated and they used a lot of divs, or they just didn't support padding.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The examples you found in alistapart.com are as complicated as they need to be, and every serious example that you can find about those layouts supports padding. You will find (and already found) a lot of good examples about it in the internet, just spend some time trying to understand them and you will see that they are not so complicated, in the end.

Anyway, I have a good demo layout similar to the second you are looking for, here:
http://www.meiaweb.com/test/BMS_DM_NI/

Basically, the html is this:

```
<body>
        <div id="head">
            <h1>Title</h1>
        </div>
        <div id="main">
            <div id="navigation">

               <!-- navigation content -->

            </div>

            <div id="content">
                <h2>Content Title</h2>
                <p>
                   <!-- main content here -->
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
```

And the css is:

```
html {
    overflow: auto;
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    line-height: 1.5em;
}

#head {
    height: 20px;
    background-color: #666;
    color: #AAA;
    padding: 20px 20px;
}


#navigation {
    width: 210px;
    padding: 20px 20px;
    background: #efefef;
    border: none;
    border-right: solid 1px #AAA;
    float: left;
    overflow: auto;
}

#content {
    margin-left: 250px;
    padding: 20px 20px;
}
```

I think it's simple enough, and it works in all modern browsers.

Comment: This will get me close enough to the answer i'm searching for.
Thanks

Answer (score 14):

Check this site out:

http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/perfect-stacked-columns.htm

Other layout examples from the above:
http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/perfect-2-column-left-menu.htm
http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/perfect-2-column-right-menu.htm
http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/perfect-3-column.htm

Comment: Those don't have full page height columns though. Unless i'm missing something?

Comment: Im sorry I should have pointed you to the other tabs on that page (i just copied my book mark).. the other tabs have 2 columns, 3 columns, left/right, full-page etc:
http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/perfect-2-column-left-menu.htm
The tabs are towards the top

Comment: Thanks. I've looked into that but i wasn't able to have the heights on them take up the full page unless there is content that takes up the full page. It maintains equal columns, but i want the columns to take up the full page regardless of if there is enough content or not. 

Take care

Comment: +1. This is extremely awesome. I can't believe I haven't seen it before.

Answer (score 7):

I know that it's badwrong to do, and I'm a semantic coder through-and-through (that wasn't meant to rhyme), but I still use a single layout table to do columns.

Why?  It's interoperable and simple.  It doesn't require ridiculous CSS hacks that just *barely* hold things together (seriously, floats are meant for typography, *not* layout).  It displays identically in every browser in current use.  It. Just. Works.  It's a semantic hack, but sometimes you just gotta do what you gotta do.

However, there is light on the horizon.  The table-* display values for CSS make equal-height columns trivial, though they can still violate source order (you still need your left-most column to be before your center column, even if it's a nav section and should come near the end of your page code).  IE8, and all non-IE browsers, support these already.

CSS3 Grids and CSS3 Template Layout will both solve this issue properly, but they're still quite a bit away from being usable.  A coder can dream, though, right?

Comment: can you give me an example of how to achieve this with a table? Cause i've been going out of my mind trying to figure this out and it's just not working.

Comment: +1 I thought I'm the only one, you have inspired me. Thanks. I'm back to my lovely tables.

Answer (score 4):

You can also look at [Layout Gala](http://blog.html.it/layoutgala/) - 40 examples of different two and three percent and fizxed-sized column layouts.

Answer (score 4):

I have reworked my sample template so you can see all three of your requested formats in action.

This is a CSS solution, no tables involved.  I have set this up so the side columns are fixed width the header/footer are fixed height.  Everything else is fluid.

With all modern browsers, excepting for IE7, the content is centered both vertically and horizontally.  IE7 has issues with its box model. I believe IE8 have these resolved.

The center box does center vertically in IE7 because I nested a 1 cell table in the center div as a hack around IE7 box model problems.  I know this is dumb and ugly but it was just to show it worked.

See it in action - [Three Column Full Screen Layout](http://sontag.ca/TheChallenge/Three%20Column%20Full%20Screen%20Layout.html)

I am a bit surprised this answer did not garner a single vote or capture the bounty.  It works, its simple, and it fulfills everything the OP asked for.  Oh well.

### The CSS

```
DIV { text-align: center }
#h0, #f0 { float: left; clear: both }
#h1, #f1 { height: 100px; float: none; width: 800px } 
#l0 { float: left; clear: left; }
#c0, #r0 { float: left; clear: none }
#l1, #r1 { width: 150px }
#c1 { width: 500px }
#l1, #r1, #c1 { height: 350px }
#h0, #f0 { background-color: orange }
#l0 { background-color: red }
#r0 { background-color: blue }
#c0 { background-color: yellow }

#h1, #f1, #l1, #r1, #c1
{ display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle; }
```

### The HTML

```
<div id="h0"><div id="h1">
  header
</div></div>

<div id="l0"><div id="l1">
  left column
</div></div>

<div id="c0"><div id="c1">
  <img alt="dilbert (3K)" src="../gif/dilbert.gif" height="82" width="80" />
</div></div>

<div id="r0"><div id="r1">
  right column
</div></div>

<div id="f0"><div id="f1">
  footer
</div></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.
Unfortunately, i need this to work in ie7. 
I doubt anyone at my work will be upgrading to ie8 anytime soon.

Thanks once again!

Comment: The only thing that does not work in IE7 is the vertical centering in a cell, and there is a way around it. With fixed width r+l columns, it may only be necessary for the center cell.

Comment: It appears your sample is actually using a JavaScript.

Comment: @Bjorn - uh yeah, for demonstration purposes. Have a look and learn some js at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.alistapart.com/articles/holygrail

That should be exactly what you need.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at Yahoo's [YUI: Grids builder](https://yuilibrary.com/).

Comment: Y!Grids doesn't help at all. It's for fixed, not fluid, designs.

Comment: yUI also supports fixed layouts.

Comment: I second this. First they do support fluid 100% layouts. 2nd They support it on many different browsers.

Answer (score 1):

I found the [Liquid two column layout at Floatutorial](http://css.maxdesign.com.au/floatutorial/tutorial0801.htm) extremely helpful when setting up a full height two column layout - fixed left column with a stretchy right column, with a header and foot row to boot. In their example, they suggest the left column is used as navigation, but it could be anything.

With Floatutorial, not only do you get a sample HTML structure and CSS out of it, but when you're done, you understand *why* you have what you end up with.

I briefly tried the YUI: Grids builder as suggestd by @JohannesH, and had some small problems with it, but the worst problem is that it was so convoluted that I had no idea why it wasn't working, or why it was supposed to have done.

**Edit:** there's also [a tutorial for a liquid three column layout](http://css.maxdesign.com.au/floatutorial/tutorial0901.htm) (which I've not used), and a whole bunch of [other tutorials that use floats](http://css.maxdesign.com.au/floatutorial/index.htm).

Comment: Thanks! do you know of a similar one with three columns as well?

Comment: No problem. I've updated the answer with a link to one that's there, but that I haven't used.

Comment: Okay so i've tried this out and noticed that the column heights are only as big as the content of the largest column. I was looking for examples that would take up the entire screen for both height and width.

Comment: Ah. I understand the full height thing now. I thought it was something else. Um. Yeah, I'm not savvy enough to know. Have you tried adjusting the container's "height" property in the CSS?

Comment: Yeah i've tried that but it doesn't work. sigh..
Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 0):

In response to a message from the original poster, here's how I would do the first request with a <table> (the others are trivial modifications):

```
<style>
body {
    height: 100%;
}

#container {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

#top, #left, #center, #right, #bottom {
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: center;
}

#left, #right {
    width: 200px;
}

#top, #bottom {
    height: 200px;
}
</style>

<table id="container">
    <tr>
        <td colspan=3 id="top">header</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="left">left</td>
        <td id="center">center</td>
        <td id="right">right</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan=3 id="bottom">footer</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks.
I've tried this but it doesn't seem to take up the full height of the page. Am i missing something?

Comment: Did you try *this specific code*?  You'll see that it does indeed fill the height of the page.  If your personal code doesn't, it's because something along the line doesn't have an explicit height set.

Answer (score 0):

There is a pre-fabbed css grid system that is based on the Golden Rule, and implements all types of column formats quite readily.  Check out [960 Grid System](http://www.960.gs).  You can accomplish your goals without the use of tables.  The nice thing that by using a pure CSS solution you can alter your layout more rapidly.

There is also a [jQuery fluid implementation](http://www.mostinspired.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2009/rip/16_fluid_jquery/) that has a fluid layout that you may be interested in.

Answer (score 0):

This should have all you need:

http://maxdesign.com.au/presentation/page_layouts/

And a more general solution to all your CSS problems:

http://www.blueprintcss.org/

Comment: Thanks.
I've tried these and while they do maintain equal height, they don't take up the full screen height unless there is content that fills up the divs.
What i'd like is a method that takes up full screen height regardless of whether there is content or not.

Comment: Too bad. At least you can still play with blueprint (although that won't solve your problem). Cheers!

Answer (score -1):

you should check out Elastic CSS Framework:

http://elasticss.com/two-columns-based-layout/

Cheers.