# Liquid Layout with fixed width left hand menu

Tags: html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>    [3 and 2 column full screen (width & height) layouts (CSS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574317/3-and-2-column-full-screen-width-height-layouts-css)

What is the simplest, CSS-only, Cross-browser way to achieve the following CSS Layout:

- A left hand menu DIV with a fixed **Pixel** width (e.g. 200px).
- next to that, a content DIV filling the whole remaining area.

I have done this before with things like absolute positioning and stuff, which never felt very clean. Now I have to convert an old table layout and think the time is right to do this properly :)

Comment: just one of many similar questions on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/574317/3-and-2-column-full-screen-width-height-layouts-css do a search for "[css] column" and you'll find more.

Comment: Thanks. The links there give me all I need. I can't close the question myself, right?

Comment: You can add a tag 'vote-to-close' or somesuch, and I imagine a moderator will come along pretty quickly to do so on your behalf.

Comment: You should be able to vote to close your own question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest seems to be:

```
<style type="text/css" media="all">

#left_hand {width: 200px;
            float: left;
            }

#main_content {margin: 0 0 0 200px; /* adjust for a gutter between divs */ }

</style>

<div id="left_hand">
<!-- content -->
</div>

<div id="main_content">
<!-- main content -->
</div>
```